# Error during create an AVD in 16

Tags: android, sdk

I have installed `Android sdk version 16`. But cannot create an `AVD`.

The following command return as an error message.

```
android create avd -n sandwitch -t 20
```

**Error:**

```
Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
Error: This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.
```

The following error shows when i try to create using eclipse.

```
[2012-09-18 14:28:32 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.
```

## EDITED

SDK:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows -> Android SDK Manager -> Select and Install ARM V7a system Image

install your ADT based Image and select correct API  You Need

I hope your Problem can Be sloved my Friend

Comment: lets take a look in sdk image. There is no such things

Comment: what operating system u r using my friend

Comment: ubuntu 12.04(32bit), cpu: core2duo ram: 2GB. Other version of android works good. Only problem in android16

Comment: u have to  create a new avd folder and install the image manually